# How to Grant database open permissions programatically in ms access

Tags: ms-access, permissions, odbc

I have an MSAccess database with user level security defined.

I am trying to programatically create a new group in a MSACCESS database using C# ODBC.

This works:

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, SELECTSCHEMA, SCHEMA ON CONTAINER Tables TO NewGroup
```

So does this (obviously by providing TABLE or OBJECT and the objectName):

```
$"GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON {objectType} {objectName} TO NewGroup";
```

However when I've run these grants, the group still doesn't have open database permission. How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
GRANT SELECTSCHEMA ON CONTAINER Databases TO NewGroup
```

But I don't have permission even though I'm using the owner of the database in the connection string.

Comment: What message do those users receive when they are prevented from opening the database?

Comment: "You do not have the necessary permissions to use the <name> object" - from Access, or "Invalid user id and/or password. You do not have the necessary permissions to use the <name> object". This is because inside User and Groupi Permissions the Open/Run checkbox for the database is not ticked. This is my problem how to programatically tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find this documented anywhere, but specify `CONNECT` for the privilege, and apply it `ON DATABASE` ...

```sql
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE TO NewGroup
```

I did not test that with an ODBC connection, but it worked using ADO in Access like this:

```vba
With CurrentProject.Connection
    .Execute "GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE TO NewGroup"
End With
```

So it should work with an OleDb connection.